# Unable to query beyond a few rows with Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL (3.1.4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, npgsql

I'm in an .NET Core MVC 3.1 project, using Npgsql.EntityFrameWorkCore.PostgreSQL (3.1.4) and have configured the connection string to a remote postgreSQL DB server. I'm not using a DBContext because I need to write SQL queries. I have a regular action method inside HomeConroller:

```
public IActionResult Countries()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("About to return countries...");
            return View(DataAccess.GetCountries);
        }
```

I get countries using

```
class DataAccess
    {
        public static List<Country> GetCountries
        {
            get {
                var connString = "connection string obscured";
                using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
                conn.Open();
                var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT name, capital, population FROM country", conn);
                List<Country> temp = new List<Country>();
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        temp.Add(new Country(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetInt32(2)));
                    }

                return temp;
            }
            set { }
        }
    }
```

The error is

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidCastException: Column is null
Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetFieldValue<T>(int ordinal)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
InvalidCastException: Column is null
Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetFieldValue<T>(int ordinal)
Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetString(int ordinal)
dblabb3mvccore.Data.DataAccess.get_GetCountries() in DataAccess.cs
+
                        temp.Add(new Country(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetInt32(2)));
dblabb3mvccore.Controllers.HomeController.Countries() in HomeController.cs
+
            return View(DataAccess.GetCountries);
lambda_method(Closure , object , object[] )
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(object target, object[] parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Despite no columns being null in the DB.

However, it works if I change the SQL command to for example `SELECT name, capital, population FROM country limit 20`.

My Country.cs:

```
    public class Country
    {
        public Country(string name, string capital, int population)
        {
            Name = name;
            Capital = capital;
            Population = population;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Capital { get; set; }
        public int Population { get; set; }
    }
```

Countries.cshtml:

```
@model List<Country>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Countries";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Capital</th>
        <th>Population</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var country in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@country.Name</td>
            <td>@country.Capital</td>
            <td>@country.Population</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: According the error message, it seems that there have some columns or cells with empty /null value, please recheck your database if you allow null values for the column (Besides, please check all the table , that you don't have NULL columns, because, EF can't serialize that empty columns). Besides, in the while loop, you could also use Logging to log the reader value, and check which line will throw this exception.

Comment: Cross posted as https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/3282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly, there were null values in my DB.